# PostgreSQL-9.2 Error while restoring Database through Ant

Tags: postgresql-9.2

I have asked this question on db.stackexchange ,But did'nt got any answer.

[Error while restoring database through Ant](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76069/postgresql-9-2-error-while-restoring-database-through-ant)

I am using PostgreSQL-9.2 and I have created a function in one database . While restoring this database through ant ,Error is thrown from the function as

```
**syntax error at or near "VARCHAR"
Where: invalid type name "CUR_STOCK (v_ad_pinstance_id VARCHAR) IS
[java] SELECT sd.m_product_id"**
```

The line from which the error is thrown is

```
DECLARE CUR_STOCK CURSOR (v_ad_pinstance_id VARCHAR)  FOR
SELECT sd.m_product_id, sd.m_locator_id, sd.m_attributesetinstance_id,
sd.c_uom_id, sd.m_product_uom_id, u.stdprecision,
ms.quantity AS qty, ms.qtyorder AS qtyorder,
ms.priority
FROM m_stock_proposed ms 
LEFT JOIN m_storage_detail sd ON ms.m_storage_detail_id  =sd.m_storage_detail_id
LEFT JOIN m_product_uom pu ON sd.m_product_uom_id = pu.m_product_uom_id
LEFT JOIN c_uom u ON pu.c_uom_id = u.c_uom_id
LEFT JOIN m_locator l ON sd.m_locator_id = l.m_locator_id
WHERE ms.ad_pinstance_id = v_ad_pinstance_id
ORDER BY ms.priority;
```

What is wrong with this query ?

I have tried by changing the datatype from **varchar to varchar(32) or character varying(32)**
after the **v_ad_pinstance_id** but the same error is coming.

Pls help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert in cursors ,But Your Error has some answer .This is not the problem of data type but the way you are defining a CURSOR

I think you should change the  definition as

```
DECLARE CUR_STOCK CURSOR (v_ad_pinstance_id VARCHAR)  IS
```

Instead of

```
DECLARE CUR_STOCK CURSOR (v_ad_pinstance_id VARCHAR)  FOR
```

just give a try!!

Happy Coding.